# Did I apply pumping lemma correctly?

Tags: pumping-lemma

```
L = { w | w in {0,1}* and w has equal number of 0s and 1s }
```

Let n be the number of the pumping lemma.

I pick s = 0<sup>n</sup> 1<sup>n</sup> and y = 0<sup>t</sup> where 1 <= t <= n.

Which gives xyz = 0<sup>(n-t)</sup> 0<sup>t</sup> 1<sup>n</sup>= 0<sup>n</sup> 1<sup>n</sup> which is in L.

But xz = 0<sup>(n-t)</sup> 1<sup>n</sup> is not in L. Contradiction.

Did I apply it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm ... You were almost ! there. Just in the last statement you are not **pumping** the string `w = xyz` at `y`.

Now we start by assuming that L is regular where `L = { w | w in {0,1}* and w has equal number of 0s and 1s }` and then we will go on to prove that for any `i >= 0` the **pumped string** i.e **w = xy<sup>i</sup>z** does not contain the equal number of 0s and 1s ( **a contradiction** per se) therefore, the language is not regular :

L is given by :

**L = {0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup> | n >= 0}**

**Iff y = 0<sup>t</sup> => w = 0<sup>n-t</sup>0<sup>t</sup>1<sup>n</sup>**

Now after pumping y for i >= 0 we get

**xy<sup>i</sup>z = 0<sup>n-t</sup>0<sup>it</sup>1<sup>n</sup>**

->  **xy<sup>i</sup>z = 0<sup>n+(i-1)t</sup>1<sup>n</sup>**

Now since n+(i-1)t is not equal to n this contradicts our assumption that  `L = { w | w in {0,1}* and w has equal number of 0s and 1s }` therefore **xy<sup>i</sup>z** does not belong to **L**

**NOTE-** You also need to consider other cases like **y = 0<sup>t</sup>1<sup>1</sup> , y = 1<sup>t</sup>** etc and later on prove that these do imply a contradiction.

Comment: I think that he **has to** consider, not just **can**.

Comment: @lejlot Yes , absolutely .. in order to find all the cases to check whether the contradiction holds or not ... mm was just being bit polite ( it was unnecessary nevertheless)... updating answer thanks :)